# Join where issue mariadb 10.4.5 and not on 10.3.x

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When i do the following query on mariaDB 10.4.5 i get no results when i do it on mariaDB 10.0.36 it gives results.

Is there some change i cannot find for mariaDB or is there something wrong with this query?

```
SELECT * FROM product JOIN productlist_product ON product.id = productlist_product.product_id WHERE productlist_product.productlist_id = 12153
```

Database rows

```
product table

-------------------------
|id        |name        |
-------------------------
|1030100111|Test product|
-------------------------

productlist_product table

---------------------------
|productlist_id|product_id|
---------------------------
|12153         |1030100111|
---------------------------
```

Comment: Not possible unless the underlying data in one/both of the tables is changing as well in between the time the queries were being run.

Comment: I arrived here looking for the reason for a failing "LEFT JOIN" on 10.3.16. I also stumbled upon this [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19588) which seems to indicate there is a problem with JOIN in many current releases of MariaDB. Perhaps this applies here too?

Comment: Thanks, Alex that most likely the case. I will update my version of MariaDB